# How do I achieve find . -name "*.py" in finder

Tags: finder

How do I achieve this in finder ?

```
call_center ➤ find . -name "*.py"
./cr-web/vendor/mockery/mockery/docs/conf.py
./wsssip/build.py
...
```

I had thought it should be as simple as following, but it is not!

[image: finder find]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk is not a glob in Finder/Spotlight search.

Try the search without the asterisk: type `.py` then choose ‘Name matches: .py’ from the dropdown.

However, searching for file extensions is not the usual way to use Spotlight search, and you can't pin the filename search to the end of the filename using Finder. Instead, Spotlight can understand what a Python source file is, so you can search for `python` and choose ‘Python Source’ for more accurate searches.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite understand your words "You can't pin the filename search to the end of the filename using Finder.". What did that mean ?

Comment: @Qiulang `-name "*.py"` will match `hello.py` and not `hello.py.goodbye`, but Finder `.py` search will match both — you can't make sure the `.py` is the end of the filename.

Comment: But I find I can use search criteria name "end with" py  but I can't let my Spotlight show type search criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can also search by file extension in Spotlight.
You'll usually find those criteria stashed away under "Other" (that also includes searching for system files).

[image]